# RViz Camera & Point Cloud2

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I connect my kinect to usb 3.0 port in my netbook..

and I want to use RViz

so i follow this page http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data

but i have a problem..

Status of camera and point cloud2 are warning.

i already choose the topic.. Camera : /camera/rgb/image_color
and PointCloud2 : /camera/rgb/points

but the screen just show "No Image"

i use Ubuntu 11.10 now.. how can i fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30524/rviz-camera-&-point-cloud2/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect does not work well on USB 3.0 Ports. If possible try to attach it to an 2.0 Port. Also have a look at the openni driver console for any error related output.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4